# Tableau to R connection - script_real returning rounded fraction numbers

Tags: r, tableau-api

I'm pretty new to Tableau but have a lot of experience with R. Everytime I use SCRIPT_REAL to call an R function based on Tableau aggregates, I get back a number that seems to be like the closest fraction approximation. For example if raw R gives me .741312, Tableau will spit out .777778, and so on. Does anything have any experience with this issue?

Comment: Could you post your calculated field ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure this is an aggregation issue.

From the [Tableau and R Integration](http://community.tableausoftware.com/docs/DOC-5313) post by Jonathan Drummey on their community site:

> Using Every Row of Data - Disaggregated Data   For accurate results
>   for the R functions, sometimes those R functions need to be called
>   with every row in the underlying data. There are two solutions to
>   this:
>
> 1. Disaggregate the measures using Analysis->Aggregate Measures->Off. This doesn’t actually cause the measures to stop their
>      aggregations, instead it tells Tableau to return every row in the data
>      without aggregating by the dimensions on the view (which gives the
>      wanted effect). Using this with R scripts can get the desired results,
>      but can cause problems for views that we want to have R work on the
>      non-aggregated data and then display the data with some level of
>      aggregation.
> 2. The second solution deals with this situation: Add a
>      dimension such as a unique Row ID to the view, and set the Compute
>      Using (addressing) of the R script to be along that dimension. If
>      we’re doing some sort of aggregation with R, then we might need to
>      reduce the number of values returned by filtering them out with
>      something like:
>
>    `IF FIRST()==0 THEN   SCRIPT_REAL('insert R script here') END`
>
> If we need to then perform additional aggregations on that
>   data, we can do so with table calculations with the appropriate
>   Compute Usings that take into account the increased level of detail in
>   the view.